# salesforce DX: Export/import products prices and price books with sfdx data:tree:export

Tags: salesforcedx, data-export

I'm need to have a post refresh script that would migrate products with prices. 
I thought using DX could save me few hours and I tried the data:tree:export command and steps described [in this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232037/dx-export-import-products-with-prices)
I'm stuck with getting this error :

```
"ERROR:  Reference Pricebook2 not found for Pricebook2Id.  Skipping record undefined."
```

for every single pricebook entry when running this export query: 
`"SELECT Name,ProductCode, (SELECT Pricebook2Id,Product2Id,UnitPrice from pricebookentries) FROM Product2".`

I'm using sfdx version 7.13.0-27 on mac. I replaced the dataImportApi.js as the post suggested. I'm not sure what elseI can do to get the export working.